# Using the trailing 's while indexing in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, sunspot-solr

I am trying to implement a sane way to search using Solr, but I am getting stuck at a particular place, I am indexing a bunch of company names. Lets say one of them is Lowe's. Now when someone types lowes, I want a result to show up, but I am unable to get this functionality working. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: For everything that is great about Solr, I'm afraid the documentation nothing of the kind...

Comment: nfechner I agree. I am having the toughest time getting the configuration to play nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, if you manage to configure your analyzers to do it one way (i.e., searching `lowes` and matching `Lowe's`), you'll most probably break the other way (i.e., searching `lowe's` and getting `Lowe's`).

One quick workaround that doesn't need black magic with your schema is [fuzzy searching](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches). Try searching for `lowes~`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to add them to the [synonym text files](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory). Also, the [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory) mentions a way to treat trailing 's by removing them. But that is probably not what you want.